# debian 12 , systemctl-timesyncd is inactive on boot

Tags: systemd, realtimesync

I have tried follow ways to enable systemd-timesyncd , but not working. after reboot , it still is inactive , although it's active before reboot.

1.

```shell
timedatectl set-ntp yes
```

2. 

```shell
sudo systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd
sudo systemctl start systemd-timesyncd
```

How to let systemd-timesyncd started on boot ?

Comment: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-timesyncd for useful commands to check the status of timesyncd. Also check you have NTP servers configured.